# CoffeeScript execute function on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I wrote a simple coffee script to show/hide a datepicker depending on a selected option from a dropdown and it works but it has a minor flaw - after I select the date in the datepicker and submit the form, the datepicker disappears, which, I believe, might be a bit confusing for end users. To fix this, I wrote additional function and execute it 'on window load', however this breaks my Jasmine tests in such a way that the whole test suit does not even run locally and CI.

This is the code I wrote.

1. Function to toggle datepicker on/off depending on a selected value from the dropdown

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load page:restore', ->
  $('body').on 'change', '.filter_status', (ev) ->
    selected = ev.target.value
    if selected == 'option_1' || selected == 'option_2'
      $('#datepicker').show()
    else $('#datepicker').hide()
```

2. Function to check what option is still selected and toggle the datepicker on/off

```
toggleDatepicker = ->
    selected = $('.filter_status #status').children('option:selected').val()
    if selected == 'option_1' || selected == 'option_2'
      $('#datepicker').show()
```

Execute the function when the window loads.

```
window.onload = toggleDatepicker
```

This works fine, however when I go to `http://localhost:3000/specs` to run JS tests nothing happens. I have over 200 tests and none of them are even run, all I see is just a blank page. Also it breaks my CI test build, the build hangs.
Do you have any ideas how I could work around this?

This is the whole script.

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load page:restore', ->
  $('body').on 'change', '.filter_status', (ev) ->
    selected = ev.target.value
    if selected == 'option_1' || selected == 'option_2'
      $(#datepicker').show()
    else $('#datepicker').hide()

  toggleDatepicker = ->
    selected = $('.filter_status #status').children('option:selected').val()
    if selected == 'option_1' || selected == 'option_2'
      $('#datepicker').show()
  window.onload = toggleDatepicker
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a simpler solution. I went for setting the class dynamically in my rails template by defining a helper method that returns a css class based on the query string passed from the UI form.